# Seeking open source alternative to RivEX (add-in for ArcGIS designed to process vector river networks)

Tags: software-recommendations, open-source-gis, hydrology

I wish to process a river network - for the assessment of hydrological potential. [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk/) is one addin (not free) which could be used with ArcGIS.

Is there any alternative to this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our "Focused question / Best answer" model operates. Software recommendation requests aren't a good fit for our Q&A model. There is [softwarerecs.se], but either way, you'd need to provide many more details than "process a river network" to get a useful answer.